# Static file not found in heroku

Tags: django, heroku, django-staticfiles

I want to publish a very little site in heroku but i have a problem. It's working on local server but when I push it to heroku it's broken. I have a 404 error with my images and css links.
Here my settings.py :

```
from pathlib import Path
import os
import django_heroku

BASE_DIR = Path(__file__).resolve().parent.parent

DEBUG = True
ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['******.herokuapp.com']

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'menu.apps.MenuConfig',
    'main.apps.MainConfig',
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.locale.LocaleMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'pizzamama.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'pizzamama.wsgi.application'

STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'staticfiles')
STATIC_URL = '/static/'

django_heroku.settings(locals())
```

So i've read the documentation but don't found a solution. I'm a begginer in Python and Django so I know it's not difficult but there is something that I don't understand.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Many things to check before going further because I think, reading your settings file, that you are missing many points from the Heroku documentation (https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/django-assets) :

- I don't see whitenoise installed in the MIDDLEWARE
- Did you commit a non empty STATIC_ROOT directory ? Django won't create it during collectstatic.

Warning : You published your secret key here, you need to regenerate it.

Can you share your github link ?

Comment: I went to the link and I copy paste the whitenoise part and now it works. I did not know because in the video training that I follow the trainer does not talk about it. So I thank you very much because it put me on the right path.
The code : 
'MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    ...
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
    'whitenoise.middleware.WhiteNoiseMiddleware',
]

STATICFILES_STORAGE = 'whitenoise.storage.CompressedManifestStaticFilesStorage' '

Answer (score 0):

The code who saved my site :

```
 MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.locale.LocaleMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
    'whitenoise.middleware.WhiteNoiseMiddleware',
 ]

 STATICFILES_STORAGE = 'whitenoise.storage.CompressedManifestStaticFilesStorage'
```